# merge based on a character column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes which have a column (one has more rows than the other) in common, keeping the row order the same, having seen on this website the different SQL joins that can be performed with the merge function. However, it doesn't merge row names into a single one (the columns are merged but I get many duplicates in the row names, as you can see by the output I get - see below)... how could I proceed ?

```
 bilans_18_19 <- merge(bilan_melia_2018, bilan_melia_2019, by = "bilan_consolide")
```

Here is the structure of my datasets :

```
structure(list(bilan_consolide = c("NON-CURRENT ASSETS", "Goodwill", 
"Other intangible assets", "Property Plant and Equipment", "Investment property", 
"Investments measured using the equity method"), `31/12/2018` = c("", 
"67 999", "107 588", "1 856 801", "149 437", "197 817"), `31/12/2017` = c("", 
"60 714", "102 194", "1 682 040", "135 900", "229 644")), row.names = 99:104, class = 
"data.frame")

structure(list(bilan_consolide = c("NON-CURRENT ASSETS", "Goodwill", 
"Other intangible assets", "Property Plant and Equipment", "Right of use", 
"Investment property"), `31/12/2019` = c("", "72 267", "73 408", 
"1 923 267", "1 251 255", "116 267"), `31/12/2018` = c("", "67 999", 
"76 372", "1 851 194", "1 064 130", "149 437"), `01/01/2018` = c("", 
"60 714", "67 660", "1 676 072", "1 172 344", "135 900")), row.names = 98:103, class = 
"data.frame")
```

And the structure of the output I get after merging them :

```
structure(list(bilan_consolide = c("Bank loans", "Bank loans", 
"Bank loans", "Bank loans", "Bonds and other negotiable securities", 
"Bonds and other negotiable securities"), `31/12/2018.x` = c("719 949", 
"719 949", "115 066", "115 066", "33 835", "33 835"), `31/12/2017` = c("644 515", 
"644 515", "209 482", "209 482", "", ""), `31/12/2019` = c("786 923", 
"100 343", "786 923", "100 343", "33 951", "172"), `31/12/2018.y` = c("719 949", 
"115 066", "719 949", "115 066", "33 835", "51 526"), `01/01/2018` = c("644 515", 
"209 482", "644 515", "209 482", "", "71 610")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I know this code to suppress identical columns, do you know how I could replicate it for identical rows in one column ?

```
library(digest)
non_duplicates <- df[!duplicated(lapply(df, digest))]

duplicates <- df[duplicated(lapply(df, digest))]

for(i in 1:ncol(non_duplicates)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(duplicates)){
    if(FALSE %in% paste0(non_duplicates[,i] == duplicates[,j])) NULL
    else names(non_duplicates)[i] <- paste(names(non_duplicates[i]), 
names(duplicates[j]), sep = "+")
  }
}
DF <- non_duplicates
```

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : i found a way out, but still would appreciate a code for a loop removing duplicate rows based on the value in one column (for instance here, in the names in "bilan_consolide"). Here is the code that works :

```
 library(dplyr)
 test_1 = bilan_melia_2019[,(1:3)] %>%
   full_join(bilan_melia_2018[,c(1,3)], by = "bilan_consolide")
```

And the structure of test_1, which is the desired one :

```
structure(list(bilan_consolide = c("NON-CURRENT ASSETS", 
"Goodwill", 
"Other intangible assets", "Property Plant and Equipment", "Right 
of use", 
"Investment property"), `31/12/2019` = c("", "72 267", "73 408", 
"1 923 267", "1 251 255", "116 267"), `31/12/2018` = c("", "67 
999", 
"76 372", "1 851 194", "1 064 130", "149 437"), `31/12/2017` = 
c("", 
"60 714", "102 194", "1 682 040", NA, "135 900")), row.names = 
c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are a few things here required in order to make this a bit more understandable. 
 1. What is `df`?  2. The structure you show after merge is NOT the same as `bilans_18_19`  3. Provide example `bilan_melia_2018` and `bilan_melia_2019` that illustrate your problem. 4. Show the desired output.

Comment: the code using df is a general one I found here that I use to remove columns when they are duplicates, it was to see if anyone knew a similar code to remove rows when they are duplicates ! I edited my post to show the desired output (which is test_1), I keep the post because I think the for loop to remove duplicate rows, if someone provides it as an answer, might be useful to other users. I will try and remember a desired output is needed in my next stack posts !